# Calculate image file size before saving to Disk in PHP

Tags: php, resize, jpeg, image-resizing

I am kind of experimenting with the PHP Image saving.
I want to compare the image's actual file sizes **before upload** and **after  resize/compress processing**, but want to know the file size that will going to be if I save it to the disk.

So that if the file size is less, then the newly processed file will replace old one, else no change will be made.

This is the code I am using to save jpeg image.

```
imagejpeg($this->newImage, $savePath, $imageQuality);
```

I tried getting the actual file size and size after

```
print_r(filesize($actual_file_size));
print_r($this->newImage);
```

where **$actual_file_size** gives the data by reading from tmp object file, however **$this->newImage** is giving blank (no value).

I am using **ResizeImage** class from github

Is there any way I can get the file size before saving to disk? So that I can keep the minimal size version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to calculate the size before saving it to the disk. I advice you create some kind of `temporary` folder to save the image, then check the size and if it is what you want move it to the folder you see fit, if you dont want to save it, delete it from the `temporary` folder.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it:

```
$original_file = 'original.jpg';
$resized_file = 'resized.jpg';
$max_file_size = '10000';

$original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_file);

$image_quality = 100;

do {
    $temp_stream = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    $saved = imagejpeg($original_image, $temp_stream, $image_quality--);
    rewind($temp_stream);
    $fstat = fstat($temp_stream);
    fclose($temp_stream);

    $file_size = $fstat['size'];
}
while (($file_size > $max_file_size) && ($image_quality >= 0));

if (-1 == $image_quality) {
    echo "Unable to get the file that small. Best I could do was $file_size bytes at image quality 0.\n";
}
else {
    echo "Successfully resized $original_file to $file_size bytes using image quality $image_quality. Resized file saved as $resized_file.\n";
    imagejpeg($new_image, $resized_file, $image_quality + 1);
}
```

This requires no file to be written until you've successfully found the ideal compression ratio.

This loop starts with an $image_quality of 100, then counts downward trying each new value on a temporary in-memory buffer. If gets down to trying 0 and the file would still be too big, it returns an error message. Otherwise, if it gets to a value that works, it reports that and saves the new file using that image quality setting.

If you're feeling adventurous, you could implement a binary search algorithm to find the ideal compression ratio more quickly, but this quick-fix gives the same result, albeit possibly a tad slower.

Answer (score 0):

Not really true.
There is a way..

The following piece of code works with JPEG and PNG :-)

```
    ///######## GET THE TOTAL PIXELS
    $total_pixels   = $image_width * $image_height;
    $size_at_max    = (3 * $total_pixels) * 0.001; /// **** IN KB
```

Comment: uhhhh, No. There are several factors that determine the file size of an image, especially a compressed one. Do you test your code?

Answer (score 0):

Brian's answer was a bit slow with large numbers of pictures... so I used a loop which modified by half the distance each time (how some digital volt meters work)...

So quality changes in steps 50, 25, 12.5 ... etc and can go up or down as needed...

```
$max_file_size = 100000;  //100k max saved file size               
$delta = 10000;           //10k distance off max when OK to stop optimizing...

  $n = 1;
  $quality = 100;  
  $size = image_size($image, $quality); 

  if ($size > $max_file_size) { 
    while ((($size > $max_file_size + $delta) or ($size < $max_file_size - $delta))) {
      if ($size > $max_file_size) $quality = $quality - (100 / (2 ** $n));
      elseif( $size < $max_file_size) $quality = $quality + (100 / (2 ** $n));
      else break;
      $size = image_size($image, $quality); 
      $n++;
      
    }
  }



function image_size ($image, $quality) {

  ob_start();                          
  imagewebp($image, NULL, $quality);
  $size = ob_get_length();             
  ob_end_clean();
  
  return $size;
}
```